# Application crash while accessing data element of linked list when data is NULL

Tags: ios, objective-c, linked-list, null

I am using following code to traverse through linked list in objective c

```
   const MSList *calls = linphone_core_get_calls(LC);
            if (calls == NULL)
            {
                                [self dismissCtrl];
                //how to check current is which screen is on
                //                while ((currentView == CallView.compositeViewDescription) ||
                //                       (currentView == CallIncomingView.compositeViewDescription) ||
                //                       (currentView == CallOutgoingView.compositeViewDescription)) {
                //                    [self popCurrentView];
                //                }

            } else {
                linphone_call_resume((LinphoneCall *)calls->data);
                while (calls)
                {

                    if(calls->data != NULL && calls->data != nil && calls->data != (__bridge void *)((id)[NSNull null]))
                    {
                        //crash
                    if (linphone_call_get_state((LinphoneCall *)calls->data) == LinphoneCallIncomingReceived ||
                        linphone_call_get_state((LinphoneCall *)calls->data) == LinphoneCallIncomingEarlyMedia) {
                        [self displayIncomingCall:(LinphoneCall *)calls->data];
                        break;
                    }
                   }
                    calls = calls->next;



                }
```

Application is crashing when entire list is not null but its data,previous or next value is NULL. I have added code to check if data is NULL but if it(data) is NULL, then  i will not be able to access it and in condition itself application is crashing. How to prevent this ? I have attached screen-shot for where application is crashing and what is the value that list contains at that time.[image]

Comment: In your while loop, instead of `while (calls)` try `while (calls != 0)`. An older github repo for linphone (https://github.com/guardianproject/linphone-ios-secure/blob/master/Classes/InCallTableViewController.m#L100) has example code that ensures `calls` exists this way. I'm not super familiar on all the ins and outs with structs in objective-c (I rarely use them), but I believe they're initialized to 0 so if nothing is in them `someStruct == 0` should return true. If I'm wrong, someone please correct me. I'll post this comment as an answer if it works, otherwise I think it should be left here

Comment: I  have tried with while (calls != 0), its still not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (calls == NULL) {
                [self dismissCtrl];
                //how to check current is which screen is on
                //                while ((currentView == CallView.compositeViewDescription) ||
                //                       (currentView == CallIncomingView.compositeViewDescription) ||
                //                       (currentView == CallOutgoingView.compositeViewDescription)) {
                //                    [self popCurrentView];
                //                }

            }
            else
            {

                size_t count = bctbx_list_size(calls);

                linphone_call_resume((LinphoneCall *)calls->data);


                int i = 0;

                while (calls )
                {


                    if(i < count)
{



                    if ( calls->data == (__bridge void *)((id)[NSNull null]) || calls->data == NULL || calls->data == nil )
                    {

                        return;
                    }


                    LinphoneCall *objCall =  (LinphoneCall *)calls->data;



                    LinphoneCallState state = (objCall != NULL) ? linphone_call_get_state(call) : 0;



                    if (state == LinphoneCallIncomingReceived ||
                        state == LinphoneCallIncomingEarlyMedia)
                    {
                        [self displayIncomingCall:(LinphoneCall *)calls->data];
                        break;
                    }

                    //calls ? calls->data : NULL
                   // calls =  calls ? calls->next : NULL;
                    calls = calls->next;
                        i = i+1;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                }
```